# PostgreSQL Selecting Joined Subquery columns when using Group By on single subquery column

Tags: sql, postgresql

This is what I'm trying to do, which searches for an image by tag, then sorts by the number of bookmarks the image has:

```
SELECT images_sq.*
FROM
(SELECT images.*
FROM "images"
JOIN image_tags ON images.id = image_tags.image_id
JOIN tags ON tags.id = image_tags.tag_id AND tags.name IN ('cards','clinical')
WHERE "images"."deleted_at" IS NULL
GROUP BY images.id HAVING (COUNT(tags.id) = '2')) images_sq
LEFT JOIN bookmarks
ON images_sq.id = bookmarks.image_id AND bookmarks.deleted_at IS NULL
group by images_sq.id Order By COUNT(bookmarks.id) DESC
```

But I get the error:

```
ERROR:  column "images.created_at" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT images.*
```

It's kind of strange, because the following works fine (note the images subquery joining with the images table):

```
SELECT images.*
FROM
(SELECT images.*
FROM "images"
JOIN image_tags ON images.id = image_tags.image_id
JOIN tags ON tags.id = image_tags.tag_id AND tags.name IN ('cards','clinical')
WHERE "images"."deleted_at" IS NULL
GROUP BY images.id HAVING (COUNT(tags.id) = '2')) images_sq
JOIN images on images.id = images_sq.id
LEFT JOIN bookmarks
ON images.id = bookmarks.image_id AND bookmarks.deleted_at IS NULL
GROUP BY images.id Order By COUNT(bookmarks.id) DESC;
```

Why can't I select all columns from the images subquery in the first example like I do the images table in the second example? Clearly I'm doing something wrong, misunderstanding something. How to do I do this correctly?

Edit (adding my abbreviated tables):

```
                                       Table "public.bookmarks"
   Column   |           Type           | Collation | Nullable |                Default                
------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+---------------------------------------
 id         | integer                  |           | not null | nextval('bookmarks_id_seq'::regclass)
 deleted_at | timestamp with time zone |           |          | 
 image_id   | integer                  |           |          | 

                                        Table "public.images"
    Column    |           Type           | Collation | Nullable |              Default               
--------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+------------------------------------
 id           | integer                  |           | not null | nextval('images_id_seq'::regclass)
 deleted_at   | timestamp with time zone |           |          |  

              Table "public.image_tags"
  Column  |  Type   | Collation | Nullable | Default 
----------+---------+-----------+----------+---------
 image_id | integer |           | not null | 
 tag_id   | integer |           | not null | 

                                       Table "public.tags"
   Column   |           Type           | Collation | Nullable |             Default              
------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+----------------------------------
 id         | integer                  |           | not null | nextval('tags_id_seq'::regclass)
 name       | text                     |           |          |
```

Comment: Could you provider your tables schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgres allows a construct such as this:

```
select i.*
from images i . . .
group by i.id
```

strictly because `id` is declared to be unique in the table (presumably as a primary key).

Your subquery does not provide that additional information, so you have to list all the columns from the subquery.

Comment: That's what I figured. Is there a way to provide that additional information? Is there a query syntax that would allow me to not explicitly list all the columns?

Comment: @huumn . . . Don't use a subquery.  Put all the `join`s in a single query.

Comment: I was able to remove the subquery by changing `COUNT(tags.id) = '2'` in the `HAVING` clause to  `COUNT(DISTINCT tags.id) = '2'` ... Non-distinct tags.id after the join with `bookmarks` was what made me think I needed to isolate the query into a subquery.